# How to check if at least one item is different comparing two lists?

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose that I've two list:

```
foo1<T>
foo2<T>
```

each list have as property `Id` that's an `int`, I need to check if all the ids of list `foo1` are equal to list `foo2`, what I did:

```
foo1.Where(x => foo2.Any(z => z.Id != x.Id)).Any();
```

so essentially if all `Ids` value of each item are equal should return `false`, if almost one is different should return `true`.
Both list are already ordered.

Actually i get even `true`, but it should return `false` 'cause all my items `Ids` are equal.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use All and Any Linq extension methods.

Please have a look on this approach:

```
var result = !foo1.All(x => foo2.Any(y => y.Id == x.Id));
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`SequenceEqual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx) for this:

> Determines whether two sequences are equal by comparing the elements by using the default equality comparer for their type.

Here's how that looks with your code and requirements:

```
!foo1.Select(x => x.Id).SequenceEqual(foo2.Select(x => x.Id));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way ^^

```
List<Foo> foo1 = new List<Foo>();
List<Foo> foo2 = new List<Foo>();
foo1.Add(new Foo(1));
foo2.Add(new Foo(1));
bool equal = foo2.All(x => x.Id == foo1.FirstOrDefault()?.Id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include index also as you are comparing every two elements

```
foo1.Where((x, index) => foo2.Any((z, index1) => z.Id != x.Id && index == index1)).Any();
```